# Нельзя исправить старый вопрос

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, правки, миграция

Просматривая старые вопросы наткнулся на проблему с тем, что я не могу их изменить. Т.е. нажимаю кнопку "править" и мне открывается пустое поле, без текста вопроса. В случае же с ответами всё работает, т.е. при попытки исправить ответ, открывается поле с ответом, которое потом успешно сохраняется.

Примеры вопросов:

[Что означает "@Override" перед объявлением метода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-override-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

[Как сделать чтобы табы в TabLayoutPanel были снизу, а не сверху?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/162/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B2-tablayoutpanel-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%83)

[Как построчно вывести весь список Python ???](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/251048)

[Для чего нужен static_cast, как он работает и где его применяют?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/387985/227016)

Или так и задумано?

Comment: баги переезда, вроде было уже такое. Можно скопировать из исходного вопроса в поле для редактирования

Comment: @BOPOH ну так может это пофиксить как-то можно?) В приведенных примерах вопросы то маленькие, их легко поправить, а есть большие и сложно форматируемые вопросы, с ними могут возникнуть проблемы.

Comment: можно попробовать [это](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/373), т.е. отредактировать и сделать откат к старой версии. Там, правда, про метки говорят, здесь может не получиться

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Скорее всего это происходит потому что в самом начале «пути» на ХэшКоде можно было задать вопрос без тела, то есть лишь с заголовком и метками. Мы быстро «прикрыли» это дело, но часть вопросов осталась. С большой вероятностью, новый движок не позволяет отображать вопрос без тела, и добавляет заголовок вместо него перед отображением, но тело вопроса от этого в базе данных не появляется.

Если вы видите ошибку, которую хорошо было бы исправить, в вопросе без тела, пожалуйста, скопируйте заголовок в тело вопроса и дополните необходимыми изменениями.

Обязательно следует что-то указать в поле "Описание", иначе правка не сохранится (возникнет ошибка сохранения).

Comment: Похоже что и так есть, все вопросы с такой проблемой имеют одинаковый заголовок и тело. И еще странность, все самые старые вопросы, заданы 3-мя людьми, это Nicolas Chabanovsky, stanislav и Angry Bird. И почти все отвечены тем, кто вопрос задавал. Видимо это  тоже досталось в наследие =)