# Невозможно отредактировать некоторые вопросы | Can't edit some questions

Tags: дефект, вопросы

Есть несколько старых вопросов, у которых сайт не дает открыть страницу редактирования (выводит ошибку "Не удалось загрузить сообщение"). [Пример вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/17689/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9).

> [image: Не удалось загрузить сообщение]

Похоже, это из-за того, что для них отсутствуют записи в таблице ревизий (обычно в ней должна быть запись с начальным содержимым вопроса, даже если он не редактировался).

[Список проблемных вопросов](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/808845/questions-with-empty-revision-history)

---

There are some old questions, for which the site cannot open editing page (shows "Cannot load post" error). [Example of question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/17689/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9).
 Probably, this is because the post history table is empty for them (unlike normal questions, for which it contains initial post record even if the post was not edited).

[List of bugged questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/808845/questions-with-empty-revision-history)

Comment: Был уже какой-то такой баг со списком старых проблемных вопросов, которые не удаётся отредактировать. Правда, возможный корень проблемы там не раскрывался. Не могу найти.

Comment: Забавно, что там в ответ на редактирование приходит 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Запилил ещё [багу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307231/339911) по отображению русских меток в SEDE.

Comment: @alexolut https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1798/Нельзя-исправить-старый-вопрос ? Это связанная проблема, но другая: у тех вопросов в истории ревизий отсутствует тело (заголовок и метки есть). Их можно отредактировать, если указать непустой комментарий к правке. Так что те вопросы не требуют вмешательства разработчиков, я думаю.

Comment: Точно. Тот вопрос, о котором я говорил. Подправил там ответ, и сами вопросы проблемные заодно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, пожалуйста, не трогайте вопрос! Это один из немногих примеров унаследованного форматирования, которое никогда не получится воспроизвести на SO (я про выравнивание последней строки по правому краю). Считайте невозможность его редактирования своего рода исторической блокировкой.

Comment: @Arhad ну и кому надо смотреть на это правостороннее "спасибо", требующее выпиливания? [Прикрутят арабский глобально](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5303/339911) с `&rlm;` и будете выравнивать по правой стороне сколько угодно. А сейчас и другими средствами можно попытаться такое [сымитировать](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307257/339911). В общем, призыв не трогать мне не ясен.